# What is the A1 Notation for Google Sheets API if I want to get the same specific set of columns in all the sheets in the spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I am trying to read the ranges A2-K for however many sheets there are in the spreadsheet, but I don't want to manually add "ranges: ['Sheet1!A2:K', Sheet2!A2:K', etc...]".  Is there any way in A1 Notation I can do this for browser javascript? Thanks.

Here is a quick example:

```
var params = {
    spreadsheetId: ID,

    ranges: ['A2:K'],

    includeGridData: true,
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, there are no methods for updating cells of all sheets in a Google Spreadsheet by giving only one a1Notation. In this case, as a workaround, how about creating the a1Notations including the sheet names using a script instead of the manual operation? If this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: You can also fill a Feature Request on Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191608&template=823917). If you do, make sure to fill the given template.